# Referencing a compiled help file (CHM) from a python toolbox (PYT)

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox

I have a python toolbox and the client wishes to have the side help pane show help. The only way I know of to do this is reference a chm help file. That option is grayed out for python toolboxes (.pyt) but not for toolboxes with scripts (.tbx, the route I don't want to go).

Does anyone have any insight or have accomplished such a feat?

Answer (score 5):

In a Python Toolbox you can create help for the side pane by editing the *Item Description* for the tool.  To do this you can right-click on the tool in your toolbox

[image]

Click *Item Description* which will open a new dialog.  Click on *Edit* and you can edit the details.

[image]

These details you add to the Summary will be shown in the help side pane.

[image]

The other details will be shown in a browser when you click on Tool Help, or when you open Item Description

Item Description:
[image]

Browser shown after clicking "Tool Help" from the tool:
[image]

The help for the toolbox and for each tool is stored in `.xml` files.  There is a separate `.xml` file for each tool.

[image]

For more info see [Documenting a tool in a Python toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/documenting-a-tool-in-a-python-toolbox.htm)